# Counting TRUE for Values obtained from if function

Tags: excel-formula

I have applied if formula to display TRUE or False when condition is TRUE and false respectively. However, the count formula is unable to count the number of Trues obtained from the aforementioned formula even when I reference the cell with the value TRUE or use direct reference as "TRUE" in the formula. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to reference the value of TRUE to countif?

Comment: Look into COUNTIF or COUNTIFS

Comment: Using countif and countifs both are not able to do the Job.

Comment: What data do you have, what condition(s) to meet, what was the attempt(s) you performed which did not work while you expected it to do what?

Comment: So lets say in A column I have list of State and in B column I have list of Visiting Places. I applied =isnumber(search("Tamilnadu",A1)) formula in C1 and then applied =isnumber(search("dolphin nose",B1)) formula in D1 then in E1 I applied =if(or(C1="TRUE",D1="TRUE"),"TRUE","FALSE"). In this E column I am trying to count the number of TRUE which is not happening. I have used countif and countis both, tried cell referencing and direct text referencing nothing worked. The result is displayed as 0.

This is just an example of the problem. The problem is same but the data I am using is different

Comment: The problem is that your countif doesn't produce a text string `"TRUE"`, but a value `TRUE`. Try `=OR(C1,D1)` or if you need to have 2 as a result if both are TRUE `=SUM(--C1:D1)`

Comment: PS your last comment should've been the info posted in the opening post.